# When you have a control condition, does it has to exactly the same way as the experimental condition?

Tags: control-group

So I am carrying out a research project for which I have multiple DV and covariates; A lengthy battery of questionnaires will measure these.
I am wondering if, in the control conditions, I also need to give participants the battery of questionnaires or if there is a way around this to spare the participants from extra fatigue.

Comment: Hmmm, if you only give the exposure the questionnaire then the data will be conditional on the subject completing the questionnaire.  This may create a selection bias and would also affect the counter factual estimate.  What is the purpose of only giving the treatment the questionnaire?

Comment: We are talking about seven questionnaires in a within cross-over design, which in par will lead the participants to repeat the same battery of tests four times- I am trying to find a solution for a potential questionnaire fatigue